# Validation curve/RandomizedSearchCV difference train and test score

Tags: random-forest, cross-validation, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

Ive build a RF model for an imbalanced data set that after feature selection has an F1 score of 54.26%. I am now trying to do hyper parameter tuning using RandomizedSearchCV, after creating validation curve plots for each hyper parameter to identify a more promising grid.

However, when I create the validation curve plots and execute the RandomisedSearchCV **both using train data only**, there is a huge difference between the train- and validation set (Cross validation "test set") f1 score performance: train f1 score is 99%+ and validation f1 score is close towards test data set f1 score). This is something I would except since I am training on the train data and then predicting on it (basically giving it the answers). Yet when I see other examples online their train- and validation scores lie very close together and they also do the validation curve plots/RandomizedSearchCV on train data only. Anyone has any idea what I could be doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This means that your model overfits. Are you using any kind of oversampling/undersampling method in order to deal with the imbalance by any chance?

Comment: What hyperparameter space/optimum?  Which "other examples online"?

Comment: I am using under sampling, however I turned this off during RandomizedSearchCV and/or plotting the validation curves as I noticed validation F1 score became not representative anymore of the actual test F1 score.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/optimizing-hyperparameters-in-random-forest-classification-ec7741f9d3f6 . This is the example I mean, although accuracy is used here as test metric.